# 16.04 keeps waking up unmounted USB drives

Tags: hard-drive, usb-drive, gvfs, sata, standby

I don't know if anybody else has experienced this, but i did on two systems on which i installed 16.04.

Essentially, if i plug a USB drive, unmount it (eject it in Nautilus), and put it to sleep (hdparm -y), i can hear the motor spinning down.

However, after a variable amount of time, the disk spins up again, and hdparm -C reports the disk to be active/idle again.

I also tried to disable gvfs from handling the drive, by putting its uuid into fstab, but even this does not help. Even with the disk unmounted, i keep getting it woken up by the system and i don't know why.

Can somebody suggest a way to diagnose what process might be responsible?

Comment: Did you use `hdparm -y` or `hdparm -Y`?

Comment: i use -y, on all systems (meaning also the 14.04 where it stays in standby until i access the drive with, like, an ls)

Comment: See if anything interesting appears in `dmesg` after it spins back up.

Comment: Nothing shows up there it seems